# Custom C++ classes, cannot overload the correct operator

Tags: operator-overloading

heres the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class Author {

public:

    Author() = default;

    ~Author() {
        delete[] _IDs;
        _IDs = nullptr;
    }

    Author(const char* Name, const char* BirthDate, const int ID)
        : _name(Name)
        , _birthdate(BirthDate)
        , _ID(ID)
    {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++) {
            if (ID == _IDs[i]) {
                delete[] _IDs;
                _IDs = nullptr;
                throw new std::invalid_argument("ID Must be UNIQUE;");
            }
        }
            
        check_alloc_ID_size();
        _IDs[_size++] = ID;
    }


    Author(const Author& other)
        : _name(other._name)
        , _birthdate(other._birthdate)
        , _ID(other._ID)
    {}

public:

    const char* GetBD() const { return _birthdate; }

    const char* GetName() const { return _name; }

    const int GetID() const { return _ID; }


private:
    const char* _name;
    const char* _birthdate;
    const int _ID;

    static int* _IDs;
    static int _size;
    static int _alloc_size;

private:

    void check_alloc_ID_size() {
        if (_size == _alloc_size) {
            int* temp = _IDs;
            _alloc_size *= 2;
            _IDs = new int[_alloc_size];

            for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++) {
                _IDs[i] = temp[i];
            }
            delete[] temp;
        }
    }
};

int* Author::_IDs = new int[1];
int Author::_size = 0;
int Author::_alloc_size = 1;

class Book {

public:

    Book(const char* title, const char* isbn, const int year, const Author& author)
        : _title(title)
        , _isbn(isbn)
        , _year(year)
        , _author(author)
    {}

    const char* GetTitle() const { return _title; }
    const char* GetIsbn() const { return _isbn; }
    const int GetYear() const { return _year; }
    const Author& GetAuthor() const { return _author; }

    void PrintBookInfo() {

        printf("%s\n%s\n%d\n", GetTitle(), GetIsbn(), GetYear());
    }

    bool operator==(const Book& other) const {
        return _isbn == other._isbn;
    }


private:
    const char* _title;
    const char* _isbn;
    const int _year;
    const Author& _author;

};

class Patron {
public:

    Patron() {}

    bool operator==(const Patron& other) const {
        return _libID == other._libID;
    }
    
private:

    const char*     _name;
    const char*     _libID;
    vector<Book>    _checked;
};


class Library {

public:

    Library()
    {}

    void AddBook(const Book& book) {
        _books.push_back(make_pair(book, 1));
    }

    
    void RemoveBook(const Book& book) {
        for (auto it = _books.begin(); it != _books.end(); ++it) {
            if ((*it).first == static_cast<const Book&>(book)) {
                _books.erase(it);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    

    void AddPatron(const Patron& patron) {
        _patrons.push_back(patron);
    }

    
    void RemovePatron(const Patron& patron) {
        for (auto it = _patrons.begin(); it != _patrons.end(); ++it) {
            if (*it == patron) {
                _patrons.erase(it);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    


private:
    
    vector<pair<Book, int>> _books;
    vector<Patron>          _patrons;

    vector<Book>            _checked_out_books;
    vector<Book>            _available_books;
};
```

Now the error is in the RemoveBook() function, and it pertains to an operator not being overloaded.
I triet multiple solutions and even chat GPT couldn't figure it out. IF you aren't SURE it works, I probably already tried it. Any thanks greatly welcome!

It says to add more details. At first I was adding operator overloads in the Book class, then realised that the _books if in the library class. Im comparing Pair<> here so I'm not sure how the operator should go. Like I said I spent 3 hours with chatGPT giving me the wrong answers.

The iterator continuation doesn't matter like GPT suggests, you can just break out of the code, even though I tried that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class Author {

public:

    Author() = default;

    ~Author() {
        delete[] _IDs;
        _IDs = nullptr;
    }

    Author(const char* Name, const char* BirthDate, const int ID)
        : _name(Name)
        , _birthdate(BirthDate)
        , _ID(ID)
    {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++) {
            if (ID == _IDs[i]) {
                delete[] _IDs;
                _IDs = nullptr;
                throw new std::invalid_argument("ID Must be UNIQUE;");
            }
        }
            
        check_alloc_ID_size();
        _IDs[_size++] = ID;
    }


    Author(const Author& other)
        : _name(other._name)
        , _birthdate(other._birthdate)
        , _ID(other._ID)
    {}

public:

    const char* GetBD() const { return _birthdate; }

    const char* GetName() const { return _name; }

    const int GetID() const { return _ID; }


private:
    const char* _name;
    const char* _birthdate;
    int _ID;

    static int* _IDs;
    static int _size;
    static int _alloc_size;

private:

    void check_alloc_ID_size() {
        if (_size == _alloc_size) {
            int* temp = _IDs;
            _alloc_size *= 2;
            _IDs = new int[_alloc_size];

            for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++) {
                _IDs[i] = temp[i];
            }
            delete[] temp;
        }
    }
};

int* Author::_IDs = new int[1];
int Author::_size = 0;
int Author::_alloc_size = 1;

class Book {

public:
    Book(const char* title, const char* isbn, const int year, const Author& author)
        : _title(title)
        , _isbn(isbn)
        , _year(year)
        , _author(author)
    {}

    const char* GetTitle() const { return _title; }
    const char* GetIsbn() const { return _isbn; }
    const int GetYear() const { return _year; }
    const Author& GetAuthor() const { return _author; }

    void PrintBookInfo() {

        printf("%s\n%s\n%d\n", GetTitle(), GetIsbn(), GetYear());
    }

    bool operator==(const Book& other) const {
        return _isbn == other._isbn;
    }


private:
    const char* _title;
    const char* _isbn;
    int _year = 9;
    Author _author;

};

class Patron {
public:

    Patron() {}

    bool operator==(const Patron& other) const {
        return _libID == other._libID;
    }
    
private:

    const char*     _name;
    const char*     _libID;
    vector<Book>    _checked;
};


class Library {

public:

    Library()
    {}

    void AddBook(const Book& book) {
        _books.push_back(make_pair(book, 1));
    }

    
    void RemoveBook(const Book& book) {
        for (auto it = _books.begin(); it != _books.end(); ++it) {
            if ((*it).first == static_cast<const Book&>(book)) {
                _books.erase(it);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    

    void AddPatron(const Patron& patron) {
        _patrons.push_back(patron);
    }

    
    void RemovePatron(const Patron& patron) {
        for (auto it = _patrons.begin(); it != _patrons.end(); ++it) {
            if (*it == patron) {
                _patrons.erase(it);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    


private:
    
    vector<pair<Book, int>> _books;
    vector<Patron>          _patrons;

    vector<Book>            _checked_out_books;
    vector<Book>            _available_books;
};
```

The problem is that _books.erase() performs a std::move operation however Book can not provide a default move constructor because it has a const reference member `const Author& _author` which needs to be initialized on construction. Consequently you'd have to provide an Author& in the move constructer which you can't do because it's being called internally by _books.erase(). So you need the Book class to hold a copy of it.

For this solution to work you also need to make `_ID` in the Author class non const otherwise Author can't provide a default constructor which is necessary for the std::move.

And a little side note `return _isbn == other._isbn` does not actually compare the values of `_isbn` and `other._isbn` but rather if they are the same pointer, which they will never be since Library constructs it's own books. To compare the actual values of `_isbn` and `other._isbn` use:

```
bool operator==(const Book& other) const {
    return strcmp(_isbn, other._isbn) == 0;
}
```